# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a few tests that my team runs. While not a big issue, I would like to handle an exception a little more gracefully.

I'm attempting to resolve a page that isn't resolvable and I would like to catch the exception and either return with a logging.critical or just a print statement.

The Exception Message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

The Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver # GRANTS ACCESS TO THE WEBDRIVERS
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options # ALLOWS CHROME OPTIONS
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys # GIVES PYTHON THE ABILITY TO SEND KEY STROKES
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By # ALLOWS PYTHON TO SEARCH FOR ELEMENTS WITHIN THE DOCUMENT
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException
import logging

import time
import pdb
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


def gui_login():
  url = "https://THISPAGEDOESNTEXIST.COM:5641/" # SANITIZED THE URL FOR THIS POST.
  print("----------")
  print("BEGIN RUN FOR GUI LOGIN")
  print("----------")
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')


  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  
  try:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    # uname = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/input")))
    # uname.clear()
    # uname.send_keys(os.environ["IDENTITY"])
    # uname.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    # passw = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/input")))
    # passw.clear()
    # passw.send_keys(os.environ["PASSWORD"])
    # passw.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    # time.sleep(10)
    
    # WebElementError = WebDriverWait(driver,3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-message"]/p')))

########## TRY LOOKING FOR WEBELEMENT IN 404 PAGE ###########

    # if WebElementError:
    #   print("SANITIZED is not resolvable.")

#### TRY LOOKING FOR THE WEBDRIVER EXCEPTION

  except WebDriverException:
    print("Page Down")
          
  finally:
    #driver.quit()
    print()
```

The Full Error:

```
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x106098210>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED\\n  (...ff80df254f4 _pthread_start + 125\\n27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80df2100f thread_start + 15\\n"}}'}

def check_response(self, response: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
    """
    Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an error.

    :Args:
     - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
       object.

    :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
    """
    status = response.get("status", None)
    if not status or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
        return
    value = None
    message = response.get("message", "")
    screen: str = response.get("screen", "")
    stacktrace = None
    if isinstance(status, int):
        value_json = response.get("value", None)
        if value_json and isinstance(value_json, str):
            import json

            try:
                value = json.loads(value_json)
                if len(value.keys()) == 1:
                    value = value["value"]
                status = value.get("error", None)
                if not status:
                    status = value.get("status", ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR)
                    message = value.get("value") or value.get("message")
                    if not isinstance(message, str):
                        value = message
                        message = message.get("message")
                else:
                    message = value.get("message", None)
            except ValueError:
                pass

    exception_class: Type[WebDriverException]
    if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
        exception_class = NoSuchElementException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
        exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
    elif status in ErrorCode.HOST_UNABLE_TO_RESOLVE:
        exception_class = HostUnableToResolveException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_SHADOW_ROOT:
        exception_class = NoSuchShadowRootException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
        exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
    elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
        exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
        exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
    elif (
        status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SELECTOR
        or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR
        or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER
    ):
        exception_class = InvalidSelectorException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotSelectableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_INTERACTABLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotInteractableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN:
        exception_class = InvalidCookieDomainException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE:
        exception_class = UnableToSetCookieException
    elif status in ErrorCode.TIMEOUT:
        exception_class = TimeoutException
    elif status in ErrorCode.SCRIPT_TIMEOUT:
        exception_class = TimeoutException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        exception_class = WebDriverException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN:
        exception_class = UnexpectedAlertPresentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_ALERT_OPEN:
        exception_class = NoAlertPresentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.IME_NOT_AVAILABLE:
        exception_class = ImeNotAvailableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED:
        exception_class = ImeActivationFailedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
        exception_class = MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
    elif status in ErrorCode.JAVASCRIPT_ERROR:
        exception_class = JavascriptException
    elif status in ErrorCode.SESSION_NOT_CREATED:
        exception_class = SessionNotCreatedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT:
        exception_class = InvalidArgumentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_COOKIE:
        exception_class = NoSuchCookieException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_CAPTURE_SCREEN:
        exception_class = ScreenshotException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_CLICK_INTERCEPTED:
        exception_class = ElementClickInterceptedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INSECURE_CERTIFICATE:
        exception_class = InsecureCertificateException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COORDINATES:
        exception_class = InvalidCoordinatesException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SESSION_ID:
        exception_class = InvalidSessionIdException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_METHOD:
        exception_class = UnknownMethodException
    else:
        exception_class = WebDriverException
    if not value:
        value = response["value"]
    if isinstance(value, str):
        raise exception_class(value)
    if message == "" and "message" in value:
        message = value["message"]

    screen = None  # type: ignore[assignment]
    if "screen" in value:
        screen = value["screen"]

    stacktrace = None
    st_value = value.get("stackTrace") or value.get("stacktrace")
    if st_value:
        if isinstance(st_value, str):
            stacktrace = st_value.split("\n")
        else:
            stacktrace = []
            try:
                for frame in st_value:
                    line = frame.get("lineNumber", "")
                    file = frame.get("fileName", "<anonymous>")
                    if line:
                        file = f"{file}:{line}"
                    meth = frame.get("methodName", "<anonymous>")
                    if "className" in frame:
                        meth = "{}.{}".format(frame["className"], meth)
                    msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                    msg = msg % (meth, file)
                    stacktrace.append(msg)
            except TypeError:
                pass
    if exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
        alert_text = None
        if "data" in value:
            alert_text = value["data"].get("text")
        elif "alert" in value:
            alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
        raise exception_class(alert_text,message, screen, stacktrace)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
```

> ```
>   raise exception_class(message)
> ```

E       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
E         (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.110)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:252: WebDriverException
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -----------------------------------

I have also tried to grab the error and parse it, as well as look for the "unavailable" message from the html page, but so far no luck.

Any recommendations would be wonderful.

Comment: Post the complete code you've tried.

Comment: @AbiSaran - the full code has been added. Some parts have been sanitized.